# How to rostopic pub multiple line for std_msgs/String type topic

Tags: ros, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to use `rostopic pub` to publish `multiple line` or `\n` or `\r\r` for `std_msgs/String` typed topic.

I tried  as [YAML commandLine](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine) said. but nothing works.

Thank you!!!

> $ rostopic pub /send_BTSVR std_msgs/String  ['test'] --- ['test2'] ---

> Usage: rostopic pub /topic type [args...]

> rostopic: error: no such option: ---

> $ rostopic pub /send_BTSVR std_msgs/String  ['test'] --- ['test2'] ---

> Usage: rostopic pub /topic type [args...]

> rostopic: error: no such option: ---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248739/how-to-rostopic-pub-multiple-line-for-std_msgs/string-type-topic/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-11-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure about the approach the wiki describes, but at least in a Bash shell, the following works for me:

```
$ rostopic pub /send_BTSVR std_msgs/String "data: '\
first line

second line

third line
'"
```

note the `\` after the `'`. This allows you to continue on the next line.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [borgcons](https://answers.ros.org/users/32279/borgcons/) on 2020-05-12**:
How is this multiple lines? There are no CR or LF in the topic that is sent. This also doesn't answer how to do \r or \n in a message

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-12**:
Testing this on my ROS Melodic/Ubuntu Bionic install I see this output:

```
$ rostopic echo /send_BTSVR
data: "first line\nsecond line\nthird line "
---
data: "first line\nsecond line\nthird line "
---
data: "first line\nsecond line\nthird line "
```

etc.

Afaict, that is a multiline string encoded in a singe `std_msgs/String`. A Python node subscribing to this with `print(msg.data)` shows me this:

```
$ python ./sub.py
first line
second line
third line 
---
first line
second line
third line 
---
```

etc.

`\n==line feed==LF`, which is the standard Linux newline.

`\r` would be something else. I've not checked how to get that in a YAML string, but I would expect it to work the same way (ie: by adding the escape sequence to the string).

Did you expect `rostopic echo` to also print the multi-line string?